# How are host and services like file shares advertised on a local network?

Tags: networking, network-shares, netbios

For instance, when you look at "Network" in Windows, it's populated with hosts, printers, etc. Or when you map a network drive, shares and other resources just seem to "be there" even though you don't know the IP address of the host the share is on.  Are these resorces advertised with NetBIOS, or a different protocol? Come to think of it, when I set up folder sharing I don't see an option to advertise whether or not shares are advertised. Is there a setting for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two classes of protocols at play here, and many competing protocols for each class:

1. **Service Discovery** (browsing) protocols help you get a reasonably up to date list of the *names* of hosts and services that are available on your network, but it doesn't tell you the IP addresses you need to actually connect to those hosts and services. NetBIOS Browsing (with or without a Domain Master Browser), UPnP's SSDP, Web Services Discovery (WSD), Windows Connect Now (WCN), the "dns-sd" parts of IETF ZeroConf (Apple Bonjour), and older rarer things like Java's Jini and the IETF Service Location Protocol (SLP) are all examples of Service Discovery protocols that may be in use on your system.
2. **Name Resolution** protocols let you look up the IP addresses for the named hosts and services. NetBIOS Name Service, WINS, DNS, and LLMNR are all examples of Name Resolution protocols.

Traditionally, Windows machines have used local LAN broadcast-based NetBIOS browsing for service discovery within workgroups, and local LAN broadcast-based NetBIOS Name Service for name resolution. When Windows NT Advanced Server was introduced, it added the concept of "Windows Domains" which were like super-workgroups that could span multiple subnets, with the help of a "Domain Master Browser" running on the NT Server. It also added the "Windows Internet Name Service" to allow Windows-style name resolution to be done in a unicast way that could cross subnets as well.

Because of design flaws, implementation hassles, and unreliability with NetBIOS style browsing and name resolution, and because it was viewed as Microsoft-centric rather than an open standard, other non-Microsoft groups developed other service discovery and name resolution protocols, some of which have found limited success and stuck around (UPnP on home gateways and printers and perhaps a few other kinds of LAN devices, ZeroConf/Bonjour on Macs), while others I think are mostly forgotten (Jini, SLP).